# android SurfaceView масштабирование

Tags: android, разработка-игр, мобильная-разработка, масштабирование, android-canvas

К примеру разрешение моей игры 360 х 640, разрешение экрана телефона 1920 х 1080 или 270 х 480 (все условно). Как мне подгонять размер моего игрового фрейма к размеру экрана? Нужно учитывать что canvas будет отрисовывать множество элементов - это как минимум 2 слоя (фон, игровые объекты) и сами игровые объекты (например до 50 динамических единиц на экране). А так же, что очень важно, на экране будут присутствовать графические кнопки управления. 
Псевдокод треда:

```
class DrawThread extends Thread{ 
    private boolean runFlag = false; 
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder; 
    private Bitmap picture1;
    private Bitmap picture2;  
    private Bitmap picture3;
     // и тд 

    private long prevTime; 
    public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Resources resources){ 
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder; 

        picture1,2,3,4 и тд = //получаем изображения           

        prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    } 
    public void setRunning(boolean run) { 
        runFlag = run; 
    } 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        Canvas canvas; 
        while (runFlag) {                 
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
            long elapsedTime = now - prevTime; 
            updatePhys(); //все расчеты проводим независимо от отрисовки
            canvas = null; 
            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null); 
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) { 
                    updateScreen(); //отрисовка всех элементов на экране 
                } 
            }  
            finally { 
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }

    public void updatePhys(){
        //расчеты
    }

    public void updateScreen(){
        canvas.drawBitmap(...)
        canvas.drawBitmap(...)
    // и тд ...
    }

}
```

Comment: мне кажется, надо рисовать объекты не в абсолютных величинах ,а в относительных - относительно размера экрана. Например, этот круг должен иметь радиус 1\12 от ширины экрана, а не 45 пикселей

Comment: я понимаю о чем вы, получаем разрешение дисплея (**WindowManager.getDefaultDisplay()**), высчитываем коэффициент относительно нашего полотна и изменяем размер каждого элемента. Но мне в данной ситуации не понятно тогда, как проводить физические вычисления.

Comment: какие такие *физические вычисления*? Например?

Comment: взять например мяч из арканоида, который отскакивает от стенок фрейма. Как и относительно чего мне рассчитывать его траекторию движения, если разрешение пикселей будет на каждом устройстве разное? а фрейм подгоняться под размеры каждого отдельно взятого экрана. Может есть возможность создавать как бы свой фрейбуффер. Каждый кадр все элементы сначала отрисовываются на битмапе размером 360 х 640, накладывается фон, мяч в просчитанной позиции (траектория которого будет просчитана относительно 360 х 640) а затем этот псевдофрейм масштабируется до нужного разрешения, и так каждый кадр.

Comment: так можно, но ведь оно будет выглядеть криво, если растянуть 360х640 в 1080х1920. Вы можете считать физ. данные для 360ч640, а рисовать это все, например, с коефициентом, который вы рассчитаете при запуске - коефициент отношения 360х640 к 1080х1920

Comment: Но опять же, если вы будете физ.данные считать, и потом "растягивать", это может привести к "скачкам" по экрану.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного забыл уже за свой вопрос, исправляюсь.

```
 public void run(){
        //создаем пустой прямоугольник
        Rect dstRect = new Rect();


        while(running){
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
            //предварительно в engine передали наш framebuffer
            //наносим на framebuffer все что нужно в этом методе
            engine.updateGraphics();



            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if(canvas != null){

                //Ключевой момент. Устанавливаем нашему dstRect размеры разрешения юзера.
                canvas.getClipBounds(dstRect);
                dstRect.bottom = propHeight;
                //отрисовываем растянутый frabuffer На весь экран.
                canvas.drawBitmap(framebuffer, null, dstRect, null);

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }else {
                System.out.println("Canvas = null!");
            }
        }

    }
```